# Angularjs $watch on array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and want to find an efficient solution for my problem.

I have an array of objects as

```
var list = [
{listprice: 100, salesprice:100, discount:0},
{listprice: 200, salesprice:200, discount:0},
{listprice: 300, salesprice:300, discount:0},
];
```

Salesprice can be changed by the user or updated by backend code. My requirement is to watch each of the salesprice for changes(whether UI or backend) and update the corresponding discount for that object only.

I was considering using $watch, but can not understand how to use it to bind to each salesprice in the array and the corresponding function that changes the discount.

Comment: Seems like if a question is marked as a dupe, a link to the original should be provided.

Answer (score 2):

granted `list` is in your `$scope` you would simply watch via:

```
$scope.$watch('list', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log('changed');
},true);
```

Note the last parameters of `true` for deep watching is required. The third is optional and is referring to `objectEquality` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this does not answer my question. I need to $watch only the salesprice not the entire list and need to update the discount for the salesprice that has changed.

Comment: well, technically you are watching salesprice